# Android - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android

I know there are dozens of questions that ask about this error, but none of the proposed solutions seem to apply to my problem, at least that I see.

Here's my log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1851)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:206)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
    at com.company.MyApp.MyActivity$7.onItemClick(MyActivity.java:240)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is MyActivity.java onCreate(). You can see that a Dialog Builder is shown and given some values. Both `myDialogLayout` and `myDialogBuilder` are private class members

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // ... a bunch of init code...

    // Create a dialog builder
    myDialogLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.leaving, null);
    myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("My Title")
        .setView(myDialogLayout)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {}
        });

    // ... more code ...
}
```

Later, when a certain button is clicked in my Activity, the `myDialogBuilder` is customized a bit and then a dialog is created and shown. `myDialog` is a private class variable/member:

```
// Builder customized a bit
myDialogBuilder 
    .setMessage("custom message here");

// Dialog created from Builder
myDialog = myDialogBuilder.create();

// Dialog shown
myDialog.show();  // <---- MyActivity.java Line: 240
```

So onto my problem, when I click my button, the dialog is created successfully. But after I press Cancel on the dialog and then press the button again, I get the error seen in the log. For some reason, the activity isn't wanting me to reuse my `myDialog` dialog. It's a class member, so it is accessible from the `onClick` handler. And the `myDialog` is a new dialog every time the button is clicked, because it's created from scratch by the `myDialogBuilder.create()` every time.

Anyone know what the problem is? I also tried adding in `myDialog.dismiss()` when the Cancel button is pressed but that didn't make a difference.

Also, you can see in my `myDialogBuilder` that a custom XML layout is used for the Dialog's view. According to the error message, it sounded like it wants me to use `removeView()` in order to remove the view from being used in the Dialog. But `myDialogBuilder.removeView()` isn't a valid method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

is `myDialogLayout` a class member variable? If so then it already has a parent from the first time you show the dialog then you create a second dialog which also tries to be the parent of `myDialogLayout`. Try creating a new instance of `myDialogLayout` everytime you open the dialog.

Comment: That was the key. I removed the `myDialogLayout` from being a class member variable and instead made it local to the `onClick` handler method. That way it's a new layout that is inflated each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a primary example of why the use of the onCreateDialog() onPrepareDialog() methods are recommended.

If you're instantiating myDialog every time your button is pressed, you're trying to attach the views from the previously created dialog object (the old parent) to the new dialog.

A dialog that has been instantiated, shown and dismissed, need merely be shown again, not completely recreated.

Assuming myDialog is a class member, try checking if myDialog is is null first or not. If not null, show it again rather than completely instantiating it.

EDIT - Here's an example of what I mean, using onPrepareDialog() and onCreateDialog(). On Create creates the dialog, and each time it's shown, it is prepared and an EditText reference is gained by using findViewById and the text cleared. We're assuming here DIALOG_TEST is an integer constant, and that in layout/dialog_test.xml there is an EditText view with id edittext.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    switch(id){

    case DIALOG_TEST:

        EditText mEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        mEditText.setText("");
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    switch(id){

    case DIALOG_TEST:

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.dialog_test, null);

        builder.setTitle("Enter Something").setView(layout);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: The dialog needs to be created because it's message (and other aspects of it) are different each time.

Comment: Dialogs have a findViewById method. You should use that to get a reference to the views and then update them.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I'm also altering the `onClick` behavior for the positive button each time as well. I didn't mention this in the original post above just so I could simplify the example.